# Unable to click element although find them in developer tool in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to click an element using xpath in puppeteer, but it is not clicking rather giving me `time out error`

Here is the snippet of my code,

```
(async () => {
  const launchOptions = { 
    headless: false,
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', 
    args: ['--start-maximized','--disable-web-security','--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']};
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
  const url = "https://apps.powerapps.com/tenantId=b0890343c-876b-45dd-95c1-a6f77b90e4f4";
  const opts = {
      logLevel: 'info',
      disableDeviceEmulation: true,
      chromeFlags: ['--disable-mobile-emulation']
  };
  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(iPhonex);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(30000);
    const firstVisit = await page.waitForXPath('//div[contains(text(),"Dr P R")]', { visible: true, timeout: 60000}) 
    const first_visit = await page.$x('//div[contains(text(),"Dr P R")]');
     if (firstVisit) {
          await first_visit[0].click();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something wrong in clicking the first visit");
          await browser.close();
        }
        }
        catch(error){
     console.error(error);
     }
  finally {
    await page.waitFor(60000);
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Please refer the image attached,

[image]

Comment: for me it timeouts because the given url is HTTP 404 (maybe it requires authentication?)

Comment: Yeah it requires authentication david

Comment: I see. is the attached screenshot about the chrome that puppeteer opened, or it is your regular chrome session? if the page is rendered correctly in the chrome opened by pptr, I suggest to test the XPath once more if the elment is available in the DOM. you can do it by switching to _Console_ tab and running `$x('//div[contains(text(),"Dr P R")]')[0].click()`. otherwise if the page is not rendered correctly (you face a login page etc.) then that is the cause of the timeout.

Comment: Did you check if the click event is binded to the div ? Does a JS click work: `page.evalutate('document.querySelector(...).click())` ?

Comment: While trying so I am getting VM430:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined @david